# Ignore file in git, but still publish it with npm

Tags: git, npm

In my project tree, I have a specific folder (let's call it `dist`) that is filled with files during build. I want to exclude those files from version control, so I placed a `.gitignore` file in that folder, to ignore the files.

However, *when* I build the package and publish it with `npm publish`, I want the files to be in the package. But `npm` sees the `.gitignore` and ignores the files in the folder.

I have a separate `.npmignore` in the root of the project, but the `.gitignore` in the subfolder is respected nevertheless.

```
root
  dist
    .gitignore
  .gitignore
  .npmignore
```

Answer (score 4):

Just put another, empty `.npmignore` in the `dist` folder to make sure that takes precedence over the `.gitignore` in the same folder.

Answer (score 3):

Worth mentioning is the [`files`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files) array in your `package.json`, because you often end up duping between `.gitignore` and `.npmignore`.